# jquery change css on radio button and page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery snippet which is showing or hiding items by css depending on which radio button is selected...

```
<script>
    jQuery('input:radio[name="type"]').change(
        function(){
            if (jQuery(this).val() == 'value1') {
                jQuery('.one').css({'display':'none'});
                jQuery('.two').css({'display':'block'});
                jQuery('.three').css({'display':'none'});
            }
            else if (jQuery(this).val() == 'value2') {
                jQuery('.one').css({'display':'block'});
                jQuery('.two').css({'display':'none'});
                jQuery('.three').css({'display':'none'});
            }
            else if (jQuery(this).val() == 'value3') {
                jQuery('.one').css({'display':'none'});
                jQuery('.two').css({'display':'none'});
                jQuery('.three').css({'display':'none'});           
            }               
    });
</script>
```

It is working great but what I want to do now is have this happen on page load as well instead of just when the radio button is changed.

Whats the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could chain the `.change()` method *after* attaching the event listener.

In doing so, a `change` event is fired after the event listeners are attached (which will presumably happen when the page loads).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctdzsh3e/)

```
$('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function () {
    // ...
}).change(); // <---
```

---

You could also use `.trigger('change')` in place of `.change()` too:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmnw1uft/)

```
$('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function () {
    // ...
}).trigger('change'); // <---
```

---

Depending on where the script is placed in your HTML document, you may need to make sure it is wrapped within a DOM ready handler too!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function () {
        // ...
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more how chaining `change()` works in this case and in general?

Comment: @callback That's just how jQuery works. Most methods return the jQuery object. In this case, chaining the `.change()` method is essentially the same as adding `$('input:radio[name="type"]').change();` *after* the event listener. This jQuery article talks about chaining - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/

Comment: To get this to work, I had to add `:checked` to my selector. So: `$('input:radio[name="type"]:checked')`